# how to plot spherical coordinates in R

Tags: r, plot

how can I plot spherical coordinates(r,theta and phi) in R?

is it possible to use the `persp()` function?

I have a colection of points as well as a grid.

Comment: I did a bit of Google searching and found no R code.  However, I did find this page that shows how to convert among systems.  Perhaps you can use those equations to convert your data and plot it with standard 3D plotting code: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SphericalCoords.aspx

Comment: There are the functions `cart2sph`, `sph2cart`, `cart2pol`, and `pol2cart` in package 'pracma' that will perform these transformations for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you know [your math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_coordinate_transformations#From_spherical_coordinates), this is a fairly trivial transformation:

```
spher_to_cart <- function(r, theta, phi) list(x=r*cos(phi)*sin(theta), 
                                              y=r*sin(theta)*sin(phi), 
                                              z=r*cos(theta))

#An example dataset
data <- data.frame(r=1:10, 
                   theta = seq(0,2*pi,length=10), 
                   phi = seq(2*pi, 0,length=10))
spher_to_cart(data$r, data$theta, data$phi)
$x
 [1]  0.000000e+00  9.848078e-01  5.130302e-01 -1.732051e+00 -1.606969e+00  1.928363e+00  3.031089e+00 -1.368081e+00 -4.431635e+00 -2.449294e-15

$y
 [1]  0.0000000 -0.8263518 -2.9095389 -3.0000000 -0.5848889 -0.7018667 -5.2500000 -7.7587705 -3.7185832  0.0000000

$z
 [1]  1.0000000  1.5320889  0.5209445 -2.0000000 -4.6984631 -5.6381557 -3.5000000  1.3891854  6.8944000 10.0000000
```

Beware to use values of theta and phi in radians, not degrees.
Then you can plot using `plot3d` for package `rgl` for instance:

```
s <- spher_to_cart(data$r, data$theta, data$phi)
library(rgl)
plot3d(s$x,s$y,s$z)
```

Comment: But why not just use the `pracma` functions? They have some error-checking stuff thrown in, which is often helpful.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft why not of course. I just prefer doing things from scratch when it's that simple.

Comment: Actually that wouldn't be a bad idea for someone (wink wink) to add the `pracma` solution as another answer for the sake of completeness.